# JTextArea displaying weird error message

Tags: java, swing

I have checked all over internet looking for what may be causing this error... but I haven't been lucky. My code basically gets the text from a JTextField and a JComboBox and passes it to a JTextArea when the user presses a button. That's the code...

```
final JTextField quant = new JTextField(3);
final JTextArea list = new JTextArea(10,30);
list.setEditable(false);

JPanel entry = new JPanel();
entry.add(quant);
entry.add(optionProds);
JButton adiciona = new JButton("Adicionar");
entry.add(adiciona);
entry.add(list);
adiciona.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        list.setText(optionProds.getSelectedItem().toString() + "-" + quant);
        System.out.print(list.getText());
    }
});
finalAction.add(entry);
```

The problem is that when I press the button, the JTextArea won't display the name of the product and its amount, but the text below instead:

> Gato-javax.swing.JTextField[,134,8,37x20,layout=javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$UpdateHandler,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@2034094f,flags=296,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,caretColor=sun.swing.PrintColorUIResource[r=51,g=51,b=51],disabledTextColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=184,g=207,b=229],editable=true,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=0,left=0,bottom=0,right=0],selectedTextColor=sun.swing.PrintColorUIResource[r=51,g=51,b=51],selectionColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=184,g=207,b=229],columns=3,columnWidth=11,command=,horizontalAlignment=LEADING]

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
list.setText(optionProds.getSelectedItem().toString() + "-" + quant.getText());
```

instead of

```
list.setText(optionProds.getSelectedItem().toString() + "-" + quant);
```

why do you print `quant`? quant is a `jtextfiled` .that's not a error .this is what you get when you print a jcomponent .when you print a jcomponent you get properties and values such as location,border,margin...etc. so you should print the text using `getText()` method

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you Fast Snail.